# multiple array in while loop javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show it on page with JavaScript while() or other functions.

```
Order 0 date 0 date-order 0
Order 1 date 0 date-order 1
Order 2 date 0 date-order 2
Order 3 date 0 date-order 3
Order 4 date 1 date-order 0
Order 5 date 1 date-order 1
Order 6 date 1 date-order 2
Order 7 date 1 date-order 3
Order 8 date 2 date-order 0
Order 9 date 2 date-order 1
Order 10 date 2 date-order 2
Order 11 date 2 date-order 3
```

i tried with this code

```
order=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"];
date=["0","0","0","0","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2"];
dateorder=["0","1","2","3","0","1","2","3","0","1","2","3"];

var i=0;
while (order[i])
{
    document.write("Order "+order[i]+"  date "+date[i]+"  date-order "+dateorder[i]+"<br>");
    i++;
}
```

it is working. have any others way to do array section shortly for use infinite numbers

```
order=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"];
date=["0","0","0","0","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2"];
dateorder=["0","1","2","3","0","1","2","3","0","1","2","3"];
```

Comment: I guess you can also use a for loop

Comment: What exactly are u asking - what else needs to be done since your code is working?

Comment: Why does this have the jquery tag? Do you want a way with jquery?

Comment: @KabirUddin if at least one of the answers below solves your issue, please award one of them the green tick so this question is deemed resolved.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through an array, I would say the best way with javascript is this:

```
order=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"];
date=["0","0","0","0","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2"];
dateorder=["0","1","2","3","0","1","2","3","0","1","2","3"];

for(var i=0; i<order.length; i++){
    console.log(order[i]);
}
```

Then you can add another loop inside that:

```
for(var i=0; i<order.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<date.length; j++){
        for(var k=0; k<dateorder.length; k++){
            console.log(order[i] + " " + date[j] + " " + dateorder[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an array of objects, if you have control over those arrays. This way, your code will be more maintanable and easy to read:

```
var orders = [
    {
        id: 0,
        date: 0,
        'date-order': 0
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        date: 0,
        'date-order': 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        date: 0,
        'date-order': 2
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        date: 0,
        'date-order': 3
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        date: 1,
        'date-order': 0
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        date: 1,
        'date-order': 1
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        date: 1,
        'date-order': 2
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        date: 1,
        'date-order': 3
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        date: 2,
        'date-order': 0
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        date: 2,
        'date-order': 1
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        date: 2,
        'date-order': 2
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        date: 2,
        'date-order': 3
    }
],
length = orders.length; // cache length
```

Then iterate all orders and display desired info:

```
for (var i=0, order; i<length; i++) {
    order = orders[i];

    document.write("Order " + order.id + "  date " + order.date + "  date-order " + order[date-order] + "<br>");
}
```